# UWP application without a window

Tags: win-universal-app

I have a UWP app, that when it is launched from a secondary tile, I want to perform a task but not display a window.

By the time `OnLaunched` is called the window is already visible, and the best I can do is close the application. Is there any way to stop the window appearing in the first place?

Comment: From a user's perspective, that makes no sense - typically they would choose to pin a section of the app to go straight back to - pinning something that doesn't appear to do anything will result in your customers assuming it's broken

Comment: @RowlandShaw This is true in general. However, for an app like Native Lock Screen (WP) this makes perfect sense. When the tile is supposed to just lock your screen, the user doesn't *want* to see the actual app.

Comment: @RowlandShaw, I would agree with you if my app just silently performed a task, but what it actually does is display the native message sending UI, pre-populated with everything the user needs. They don't need to see my apps UI as well.

Comment: If your project is a UWP project than the answer is NO, but there is a workaround for the given scenario. You can create a WPF project and then wrap it in UWP project using Desktop Bridge. The best example is Sticky Notes App which does exactly the same.